# Convert \input to number

Tags: input, external-files, calculations, parsing

I'm reading several txt-files from disk and I want to do some simple calculations on them and be able to print them on the page.

Basically I have:

```
\newcommand\getinput[2]{
    \immediate\write18{do-some-things > input.txt}
    \input{input.txt}}
```

And now I want to do use that input for simple additions, like this:

```
\newcounter{mycounter}
My Input: \getinput
\addtocounter{mycounter}{\getinput}
My Sum: \themycounter
```

Comment: you could do  `\newcommand\getinput[2]{\input{|do-some-things}}` so the output is piped straight to tex with no intermediate file (although you'd still have to make it a number)

Comment: Do you need to use exactly `\getinput` in the counter setting? Or can we use a route where you call the input and save the result in a macro?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using it for executing texcount to count words in my sections. That's why I need to write it to file first

Comment: @JosephWright sure. It doesn't matter if there are any extra steps

Comment: @RazorHail why do you need to write to a file though you can pipe the output straight to tex.

Comment: you run with shell-escape enabled all the time and shell out to count words every run?, why?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I try it without, there is no output. Here's my actual command: `\newcommand\wordcount[2]{
 \immediate\write18{texcount -sub=section  #1.tex | grep Section | grep #2 | sed -e s/+.*// | sed -e "s/ //g" > count.txt}
 \input{count.txt}}` Using this command will print the contents of the file. However, when I do this, it doesnt:
 `\newcommand\wordcount[2]{
 \immediate\write18{texcount -sub=section  #1.tex | grep Section | grep #2 | sed -e s/+.*// | sed -e "s/ //g"}}`    Also, ignore the missing/incorrect quotation-marks. It's running on Windows

Comment: see Joseph's answer where he uses the technique I was suggesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need this to work by expansion if you want to use it directly for a counter, so cannot use `\write`. Instead, it's possible to exploit the piped input ability of modern engines. Using a working example with `echo`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\getinput{\@@input|"echo 1"}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}
My Input: \getinput
\addtocounter{mycounter}{\getinput}
My Sum: \themycounter

\end{document}
```

Here, we need the 'raw' behaviour of the `\input` primitive, hence needing to use it's LaTeX name, `\@@input`.

---

If you are happy with a two-step process, first saving the information then using it, you might use the more robust `expl3` wrapper around the same idea.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \saveinput { m m }
  { \sys_get_shell:nnN {#1} { } #2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\saveinput{echo 1}\savedinput

My Input: \savedinput
\addtocounter{mycounter}{\savedinput}
My Sum: \themycounter

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. I just used the second method and replaced "echo 1" with "cat input.txt"

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\newcounter{tmpcnt}
\newwrite\notesfile
\newcommand\getinput[1]{
  \immediate\openout\notesfile=input.txt
  \immediate\write\notesfile{\the\numexpr#1+\thetmpcnt\relax}
  \immediate\closeout\notesfile
  \readdef{input.txt}\inputvar
  \inputvar
}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{tmpcnt}{5}
\getinput{3}

\addtocounter{tmpcnt}{\inputvar}

\getinput{4}

\getinput{-2}
\end{document}
```

[image]